# How can I read mpp file using ACCESS VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-project

Is there a way to read a MS Project (mpp file) from ACCESS VBA??

Answer (score 0):

Heh, need to read fully. Hopefully [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/97699) will still help.